Does the cartesian product of locales preserve epimorphisms?
It is known that a commutative ring $A$ is flat if and only if the endofunctor $A \otimes {-}$ preserves monomorphisms of commutative rings.
(The most straightforward proof is to embed the category of $A$-modules in the category of $A$-algebras as nilsquare extensions of $A$.)
Completely analogously (and formally dualising), define:

A locale $X$ is flat if $X \times {-}$ preserves epimorphisms of locales.

Is it the case that every locale is flat?
(There is an argument to be made that this is not the right characterisation of flatness to generalise, but the filtered colimit of frees characterisation is not really applicable since the algebraic theory of frames is not finitary.)
The question can be restated algebraically as follows:
Let $A$ be any frame and let $\phi : B \to C$ be a frame homomorphism that is injective (in the ordinary sense of maps of sets).
Is the homomorphism $\textrm{id}_A \otimes \phi : A \otimes B \to A \otimes C$ also injective?
Thus, much as in the commutative algebra context, the problem is to somehow prove that there are no unexpected relations in the tensor product $A \otimes C$.
This is easy if $A$ is, say, a powerset (= free as a complete join semilattice).
What happens in general?

Isn't $A \otimes -$ a right adjoint here?

I thought so too, but apparently not.

As it turns out, there is a reasonably concrete description of $A \otimes B$.
The idea is that since the elementary tensors $a \otimes b$ do generate $A \otimes B$, we can embed $A \otimes B$ into the poset of downward-closed subsets of $A \times B$; the task is to identify the image of the embedding.
Lemma.
$A \otimes B$ is naturally isomorphic to the poset $P$ of subsets of $A \times B$ that are downward-closed and $\bigvee$-closed in each factor.
Corollary.
Given sub-(complete join semilattices) $A' \subseteq A$ and $B' \subseteq B$, the induced $\bigvee$-preserving monotone map $A' \otimes B' \to A \otimes B$ is injective.
Proof of corollary.
A subset $R' \subseteq A' \times B'$ satisfying the conditions of the lemma is easily extended to a subset $R \subseteq A \times B$ satisfying the same conditions:
$$R = \{ (a, b) \in A \times B : \exists (a', b') \in R' . a \le a' \text{ and } b \le b' \} \cup \{ (a, b) \in A \times B : a = \bot_A \text{ or } b = \bot_B \}$$
But $R \cap (A' \times B') = R'$, so this extension operation defines an injective map $P' \to P$, where $P'$ is the poset of subsets of $A' \times B'$ satisfying the conditions of the lemma.
Thus, applying the identification in the lemma, the map $A' \otimes B' \to A \otimes B$ is injective.　◼
Proof of lemma. Send $a \otimes b$ to the subset $\{ (a', b') \in A \times B : a' \otimes b' \le a \otimes b \}$, i.e.
$$\{ (a', b') \in A \times B : a' \le a \text{ and } b' \le b \} \cup \{ (a', b') \in A \times B : a' = \bot_A \text{ or } b' = \bot_B \}$$
It is easy to see that this assignment is monotone and preserves $\bigvee$.
It is also clear that $P$ is closed under $\bigcap$ in the powerset of $A \times B$, so $P$ has joins (not to be confused with $\bigcup$) in general, hence we have a well defined map on all of $A \otimes B$ (not just the generators).
For the inverse, send $R \in P$ to the element $\bigvee \{ a \otimes b : (a, b) \in R \}$.
It is straightforward to verify that we have a mutually inverse pair of monotone maps.　◼
